# @DeclareParents annotation in Introductions in Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am doing Spring Aspect Oriented Programming with annotations in Java. I have an Aspect LogAOP:

```
@Aspect
public class LogAOP {

  @DeclareParents(value="beans.service.*+",     //Line 1
                  defaultImpl= EventImpl.class)
  public static Event mixin;

  @Before("com.beans.business.businessService() &&" +
          "this(abc)")
  public void usage(Event abc) {
    abc.increment();
  }

}
```

I am not able to understand the significance of '+' symbol in Line 1 in value attribute of @DeclareParents annotation.
Beacuse even if I remove this + symbol, the program is running fine. I have also searched in official documentation of Spring AOP (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/aop.html) , nothing is mentioned there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `+` after a class name or interface name is used to match that class or interface, and all it's subclasses. So, the pointcut expression in this case:

```
@DeclareParents(value="beans.service.*+",     //Line 1
              defaultImpl= EventImpl.class)
public static Event mixin;
```

...will match any interfaces or class defined in package `beans.service`, and also any subclass or implementing class of those classes and interfaces. It may be needed because, the implementing classes might not be in the `beans.service` package. In your case, you're not seeing the effect because may be all your implementing classes are in the same package. Try implementing an interface in `beans.service` package, and put the implementing class in a different package. I guess, you'll see the difference then.